# Python list index out of range regarding massive iterations only

Tags: python, list

I have a big text file,
where each line is according to a define syntax (which been handled with a regex).

I'm getting the following error:

```
remainder = '{} {} '.format(*pieces[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

on this code:

```
def open_delimited(filename, args):
    with open(filename, args, encoding="UTF-16") as infile:
        chunksize = 10000
        remainder = ''
        for chunk in iter(lambda: infile.read(chunksize), ''):
            pieces = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s+(\d+_\d+)\s+(((post)\s+1)|((\d+_\d+_\d+)\s+(comment)\s+2))(.+)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s+(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*)", remainder + chunk, re.IGNORECASE)
            for piece in pieces[:-1]:
                yield piece
            remainder = '{} {} '.format(*pieces[-1])
        if remainder:
            yield remainder


filename = 'data/AllData_2000001_3000000.txt'

for chunk in open_delimited(filename, 'r'): 
    for j in range(len(chunk)):
        print(chunk[j])
```

When I'm limiting the number of iterations, the code work fine.

```
i = 0
for chunk in open_delimited(filename, 'r'): 
    if (i <= 1000):
        for j in range(len(chunk)):
            print(chunk[j])
    else:
        break
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the regex doesnt find a piece in the chunk it will return an empty list and hence the error.

```
>>> pieces = []
>>> pieces[-1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you expected to find pieces in every chunk then the next question is why are you not getting a piece in a particular chunk. I would continue debugging as follows

```
try:
    remainder = '{} {} '.format(*pieces[-1]) 
except IndexError:
    print pieces
    print chunk
    raise
```

Comment: `raise` with no argument beats `raise IndexError` here. It'll reraise the original `IndexError`, with the original traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible `pieces` is empty?

```
>>> [][-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My best guess is that `re.findall` is sometimes failing to find anything.